# Trying to use glob to iterate through files in a folder in python

Tags: python, glob

I keep just getting the data i want from the last file in the list. I appreciate the program working that much, but i would rather it worked through all of the files in the folder.

```
   import os
   import glob
   os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\Arcgis\Text_files\Data_exports')
   for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):
       reader = open(file)

   from EXPORT_COLUMN_SET import *

   try:
        data = column_set(reader)
        data.start_data_printer()
   finally:
        reader.close()
```

Comment: Why are you doing `list(glob(…))`? `glob` already returns a list. And even if it returned some other kind of iterable, why would you care whether it's a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scope of the for loop defines what is done for each file. Everything after the for loop is only done once:

```
 import os                                                                   
 import glob                                                                 
 os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\Arcgis\Text_files\Data_exports')         
 for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):                                       
     reader = open(file)               # <-- Things done for each file

 # Things done only once:                      
 from EXPORT_COLUMN_SET import *                                             

 try:                                                                        
      data = column_set(reader)                                              
      data.start_data_printer()                                              
 finally:                                                                    
      reader.close()
```

You can indent the rest of the code to put it inside the for loop:

```
 import os                                                                   
 import glob                                                                 
 os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\Arcgis\Text_files\Data_exports')       
 for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):                           
     reader = open(file)                  # ^                 
                                          # |                
     from EXPORT_COLUMN_SET import *      # |              
                                          # | Things now done for each file
     try:                                 # |                                 
          data = column_set(reader)       # |                              
          data.start_data_printer()       # |                              
     finally:                             # |                              
          reader.close()                  # v
```

Comment: Ya i cant believe i didnt see that how silly of me. Thanks a ton! Its friday afternoon............

Comment: Instead of `list(glob.glob(…))` (i.e. building a list to iterate over) use [glob.iglob(…)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) instead: returns an iterator and thus saves creating a list.

Answer (score 4):

After the loop `reader` will contain the last opened file, then you process that single file.

Fix the indentation.

Comment: An indentation issue. Ya that seemed to do the trick. Ya its f***ing friday afternoon. Thanks!!